# Expected number of hyperplane cuts to partition a $d$-dimensional hypercube of side length $n$ into pieces of unit volume

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value, geometric-probability

I came up with the following question and am not certain of its solution. Has this problem or problems like it be tackled before?

Let $H_d$ be the $d$-dimensional hypercube $[0,n]^d \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Define a cut to be a hyperplane which intersects $H_d$. In expectation, how many uniformly sampled cuts are needed so they partition $H_d$ into pieces that all have unit volume or less?

I speculate the answer is $O(n^d \log(n))$.

The one dimensional version of the question is posted separately [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635848/expected-number-of-cuts-to-partition-the-interval-0-n-into-segments-of-unit), where the answer is $\Theta(n\log(n))$

Comment: I doubt there would be an easy way to obtain an exact asymptotic answer. In fact, I would be surprised if there was an easy way to get an upper bound which is anywhere close to being sharp. A simulation might yield reasonable estimates, but unless $d$ is very small, the implementation of the simulation will run into difficulty finding, after each cut, the convex pieces and their volumes. I would start with the case $d=2$. If you can't get that done, then forget the general problem.

Comment: @quasi I originally started with the 2 dimensional case and got stuck. I then went to one dimensional and am still stuck, although this case feels at least a little bit more manageable.

Comment: Why not just ask the case $d=1$ as its own question. At least for that case, I suspect someone will be able to offer a useful response. I think the general case is probably out-of-range for MSE. It seems more of a fit for a research project, rather than an MSE-type question.

Comment: @quasi Seems reasonable. Per Stack Exchange rules, am I allowed to keep this question up if I want to post the one dimension case as its own?

Comment: Sure, and give a link back to this one.