# Expected number of cuts to partition the interval $[0, n]$ into segments of unit length or less

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-geometry

This is the one dimensional case of a more general problem I posted, linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635773/expected-number-of-hyperplane-cuts-to-partition-a-d-dimensional-hypercube-of-s).

Given an interval of length $n$, define a cut as a point somewhere in the interval. In expectation, how many uniformly sampled cuts are needed to partition the interval into segments of unit length or less?

The obvious lower bound is $O(n)$ and I speculate the answer is $O(n\log(n))$, but I don't really know how to approach this question. Has this problem or a similar problem been tackled?

Comment: Each new cut is a uniform point in $[0,n]$ regardeless of previous stuff?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo yes that's right

Comment: Why $n$ instead of $x$? Doesn't it make sense to let $n$ be real?

Comment: Do you want an explicit formula, or is proving it is $O$ of something enough?

Comment: It could be $x$, although me being discrete-minded put it as $n$.

Comment: I don't really want anything in particular. I'm just really curious about this problem. I don't even know if it has an explicit solution...

Comment: It reminds me of coupon collector, which would support $O(n \log(n))$.  Roughly speaking, you need one cut in each unit of the interval, which is like the coupons.

Comment: @RossMillikan Interesting! Cutting the interval into 2n equal pieces, I think this is enough to give $O(n\log(n))$ as an upper bound. I wonder if it is tight

Comment: yeah, that definitely gives the bound

Comment: You can also split into blocks of size $1$ and get the same lower bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least one point in each interval of the form $(k, k+1)$ for whole $k$.  The coupon collector problem argument says this takes $n \log n + \gamma$ points.  If you get one point in every interval of the form $(k, k+\frac 12)$ and $(k+\frac 12, k+1)$ that is guaranteed to be sufficient.  The same coupon collector argument says this takes $2n \log(2n) + \gamma$ points, which is also $O(n \log (n))$ so we have the big-O class of the answer.

Thanks to Jorge Fernández Hidalgo for the half unit idea.